# Static IP with "kubectl expose" on Google Container Engine stays in <pending> state forever

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I am trying to expose a kubernetes "deployment" via the `kubectl expose` command, wih a static IP address, on Google Container Engine.

With an ephemeral IP, everything works fine:

```
kubectl expose deployment my-application \
    --type="LoadBalancer" --port=80 --target-port=8080
```

I use `kubectl get services` and wait a few minutes to see the ephemeral IP having been assigned. I enter the IP in my browser and I see the applicaiton, i.e. everything works.

However, when I do the following:

1. Create a static IP address using the gcloud web interface (Networking -> External IP addresses -> Reserve Static IP address)
2. Re-create the service with the same command as above but with the extra `--load-balancer-ip` option

   ```
   kubectl expose deployment my-application \
       --type="LoadBalancer" --port=80 --target-port=8080 \
       --load-balancer-ip='1.2.3.4'   # IP as assigned by web interface above
   ```

The command is successful, but the application is not reachable under that IP address, and when I use the following command:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
endpoints    10.119.247.39   <pending>     80/TCP    23m
kubernetes   10.119.240.1    <none>        443/TCP   1d
```

I see that the `EXTERNAL-IP` is still `<pending>` although I've waited 23 minutes so far.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The command you provided worked for me. In a first attempt to exposed the service I used a static IP address defined in a different region from where the Load Balancer was being created. As a result the Load Balancer was not created and the service kept in a "Pending" state.

```
$ kubectl get services | grep node3
hello-node3   10.3.242.65    <pending>      80/TCP     1m
$kubectl get events  
48s        2m          5         hello-node3   Service               Normal    CreatingLoadBalancer         {service-controller }   Creating load balancer
47s        2m          5         hello-node3   Service               Warning   CreatingLoadBalancerFailed   {service-controller }   Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load balancer for service default/hello-node3: requested ip W.X.Y.Z is neither static nor assigned to LB a059cdb738ef911e6a83642010af001b(default/hello-node3): <nil>
```

Then I used an IP defined in us-central where my nodes lives.

```
kubectl expose deployment hello-node3 --type="LoadBalancer" --target-port=8080 --load-balancer-ip='A.B.C.D'
```

Then:

```
$ kubectl get services | grep node3
hello-node3   10.3.241.0     A.B.C.D   80/TCP     20m
$ curl A.B.C.D
Hello World!
```

I would suggest making sure the IP exists in the same region the cluster lives. If that fails, to obtain more information on the state by using `kubectl get events`. That might shed some light.